# IPhone App - Consolidating Web Service API Calls

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

Lets say you have an iPhone Application that connects to your own backend API (PHP, Python, etc).  In your iPhone App, you'll be using the Google Maps API and storing unique identifiers to Google's locations in your backend's database.

My question is: Lets say you now need to retrieve this stored data.  Does it make sense to --

A) Make a request from the iOS App, to your backend API and retrieve the Data (including the Google ID of the location(s) stored).  Then once the iOS app receives this data, make another request from the iOS App, to the Google API to retrieve the details of a location based on the unique ID (lets say it's Address, phone number, store hours that you need).

OR

B) Make a request from the iOS application to your backend API.  When your API receives certain requests (i.e. ones pertaining to locations) your backend makes a call to Google's API to retrieve the locations details, and returns all the data to the iOS App.

OR

C) ??

In general, should the calls to a 3rd party API be relegated to either the iOS App or your backend?  Obviously, I can think of several circumstances where it makes the most sense for the iOS App to communicate directly with the Google API (i.e. Real Time Searching for a location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having more of the complex logic in the backend gives you a bit more flexibility in the long run, since the deployment process for your backend code can happen at your own schedule, not Apple's (which takes weeks). I highly recommend that you keep as much logic as it makes sense to your in your web service, and keep your app relatively "dumb".

As you mentioned, there are some disadvantages to this approach, mainly in the delay of your service having to communicate with other services. You will have to test this an see if the lag is good enough for your application.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured it made most sense to keep as much as I could in my API. Perhaps it's only the search functionality that should be based in the App, and I can experiment with load times for the rest via my API